# Is PhoneGap support Nokia x

Tags: cordova, android-x86, nokiax

i am design camera application in nokia x which is support both windows and android can any one help me to open camera Application using phone gap in nokia x 
Thanx

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some code you have attempted and read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, also in your plugins, if you are using only parts available for the AOSP on the required API level(16 or 18), then you could use the same code in all android devices and Nokia X as well.

For parts that are requiring the Nokia X specific implementation, I have some alpha level examples available in my [github repo](https://github.com/DrJukka/PhoneGap), will try working a bit more on those once I get back from my vacation